# AutoPostBack= "true" not functioning properly with dropdown list asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, autopostback

I have a dropdown list that is populated with values from a DB table, when you select a value from the list a repeater appears and shows extra details about that selected value. The only problem is that the page only refreshes for the first value selected, if you try to make a different selection the page doesn't change.

The repeater seems to be working fine, but there must be something wrong with the AutoPost back in the dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" Width="150px" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="LCID" DataValueField="LCID" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack= "true" >

 </asp:DropDownList>
```

this is the code from the aspx.cs file:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Redirect("http://localhost:31003/?LCID="+ DropDownList1.SelectedValue);


}
}
```

If anyone can see what I am missing from my program I would be very grateful, thanks.

Comment: What is the use of DataSourceID when you are binding on pageload ?

Comment: I created this dropdown using the configure data source functions in the design view of visual studio, so most of that was already there apart from the autoPostBack. I removed it, but the DataSourceID is what gets the values from the DB table, without it the dropdown is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the `PageName` in  `Response.Redirect`

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/PageName.aspx?LCID="+ DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
}
```

Comment: That still didn't fix the issue, probably good to have though.

Comment: Thank you so much! that seems to have fixed the problem :)

Comment: Sorry to ask another question within a question but you seem to know about this stuff whereas i'm completely new. I am trying to get a DateTime from my DB and put it into a label in my web page. I tried: <asp:Label ID="RefreshTimeLabel" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" Text='<%#Eval("date") %>'></asp:Label> but that didn't work. Do you have any suggestions?